# Why can't we use `T::Call` in pallet like `T::AccountId` and `T::BlockNumber`?

Tags: types, call

I am trying to use `T::Call` (This type is defined in `frame_system`) in storage and pallet dispatchable functions but getting below error.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as frame_system::Config>::Call: WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/test/src/lib.rs:33:1
   |
33 | #[frame_support::pallet]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::Call`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Encode` for `<T as frame_system::Config>::Call`
note: required by a bound in `EncodeLike`
  --> /Users/sm/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parity-scale-codec-2.3.1/src/encode_like.rs:73:25
   |
73 | pub trait EncodeLike<T: Encode = Self>: Sized + Encode {}
   |                         ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `EncodeLike`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting the associated type
   |
68 |     #[pallet::storage, <T as frame_system::Config>::Call: WrapperTypeEncode]
   |                      ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

However, I am able to use other `frame_system` types like `AccountId` and `BlockNumber`.
Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: Please also post the code. Are you trying to pass a `Call` as argument to an extrinsic?

Comment: @Ayush Mishra, please don't post errors without posting code. Do you expect us to be mind readers on how an error is caused?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi sorry I should have posted the code. I will take care of it next time. Thanks for your answer. It really helps.

Comment: @AyushMishra you can stil edit the question to include the problematic code in order to help new readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Call` type from `frame_system` is not the call that you want to use in this scenario. You should look at how the [Multisig pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs) handles working with the `Call` type.

1. You must define a new `Call` type in your Pallet config which represents the outer call of the whole runtime:

   ```
   #[pallet::config]
   pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
       /// The overarching call type.
       type Call: Parameter
           + Dispatchable<Origin = Self::Origin, PostInfo = PostDispatchInfo>
           + GetDispatchInfo
           + From<frame_system::Call<Self>>;

       // ...
   }
   ```
2. When referencing this type, you should disambiguate which `Call` you want to use, by referring to it by: `<T as Config>::Call>`. Where `Config` represents your pallet's config.
3. When using the `Call` as a parameter input into an extrinsic, you should wrap it in a `Box` so that it can be placed on the heap and referenced by pointer, which can help since a `Call` can be very large in size: `Box<<T as Config>::Call>`

Comment: Boxing the call is not an optional thing. You are required to box it, otherwise you would have a self recursive enum that the compiler can not get the size of. You would get a compiler error.